# Generate a dictionary composed of random strings with random lengths from random characters of the supported character set

Tags: python, string, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I need to write a python script that:

1. Get a random length for the string to generate
2. Generate a string of this length, using random characters from [the supported/valid character set]
3. Write the generated strings one per line in a text file (length >=2 million) and save this file to disk.

Following is the supported/valid character set:
**`0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüßABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜ!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]_~€§£¥`**

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you familiar with the *random* module? You'll find that very helpful. Do you know how to open/write/close a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution

```
import random

valid = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '_', '~', '€', '§', '£', '¥']

s = ""

n = 100

f = open("test.txt", "a")

for j in range(n):
    for i in range(random.randint(10, 20)):
        s += random.choice(valid)
    f.write(s+'\n')
    s = ""
```